# Execute several times the same php script without timeouts

Tags: php, mysql, apache, reporting

Im developing a system which is supposed to show reports by client. These reports need previous calculations to be done before the actual report is shown.

Since the calculation process is sometimes tedious and long, and sometimes the data that the report uses gets refreshed, the user must be able to re-calculate those reports. For those reasons, the script that generates the report is separated from the script that actually shows the report.

In short, I have two scripts, lets say they're called 'generateReport.php' and 'showReport.php'.

When an user clicks on a client to see its report 'showReport.php' checks if the data it needs has been generated already and if it is, it will show the report. 
If the data is not there, it'll forward the brower to 'generateReport.php' and when finished, it will forward the browser to 'showReport.php'

The problem arises when an user clicks on two clients and they both need theyre data generated.

The first clicked client gets to 'generateReport.php' where the user sees a bar which lets him/her know the whole process. While the page where the second client should be generated just stays there, waiting.

If the first client takes too long, the second one apparently times out and just stays there.

I understand that since im hitting the same php ('generateReport.php') on two tabs on the same browser, apache wont process both requests concurrently so, Is there a way to avoid the second (and possibly third, fourth, etc..) window NOT to time out?

Note: 'generateReport.php' and 'showReport.php' have set_time_limit(0); just for testing and it apparently does nothing.

Note2: I have access to php.ini in my hosting environment

Note3: So sorry for the longish/only boring text post

Thanx in advance!

**EDIT1:**

Thank you Twisty for your reply.

- The requests are generated by HTTP GETs by an user clicking anchor tags.
- header("Location: ...") is used to take the user from generateReport to showReport.
- I was refering to browser tabs, yes.

Comment: It's all not very clear. How does the user generate the requests, are the requests AJAX or links that load the page? What method is used to take the user from generateReport.php to showReport.php? It sounds like AJAX could be helpful here, such that an indicator of work is shown to the user when they request a report, the report is generated and returned, and then displayed. When you say 'tab' are you referring to some elements in your page or a seperate browser tab?

Comment: Thank you Twisty please see my edit! AJAX is used on 'generateReport.php', the user is shown a progress bar with comments regarding on what the generation script is doing and the time left!

Comment: How often do you need to generate your reports ? one time per day ? hour ?

Comment: Without knowing what your reports are generating, it's sort of hard to know where the issue lies. A) Are the MySQL Queries taking so long that you hit the timeout? If so, can you optimize your queires, tables, or indexes? B) Is the timeout a PHP limit or Apache limit, they both have limits, usually set to 120 seconds, 2 minutes. If you can't optimize your query, can you adjust your timeouts to fit?

Comment: Reports are needed generally once a month, for the most part as there are exceptions. Yes, the bulk of the time taken is waiting for mysql to return data. And yes, all  the queries have been optimized (proper indexes added, etc) already so theres no much room for optimization left. Regarding the PHP or apache limits, isnt it enough to set set_time_limit(0); at the beginning of a php to make it wait infinitely and not timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Apache will run your script multiple times; why would it care?

If generating the report takes more than 2 minutes, the browser itself will usually timeout and stop waiting.

The typical trick here is to have the "generate" process run in a separate thread, so it can complete in its own time.

I don't have a sense as to why the second user is blocked, but I'd think there's something blocking in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody!

We've decided to run those long tasks on idle time and have the data already generated when requested.

Web response times should never take that long anyway, and a web server shouldnt handle those long processes.

Again thank you all for your support!